# What are the limitations of Office 365 trial version in terms of development?

Tags: sharepoint, office365

I am a SharePoint developer. We are planning to migrate SharePoint server 2013 site to Office 365. As of now we are using Office trial version for development. Can any please tell me what are the limitations of Office 365 trial version in terms of development?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

There's no difference - the trial is just time-limited.

Answer (score 0):

25GB max for site folders, cant purchase add'l storage w/o a subscription